# Discrepancy between "Transactions" and "Erc20 Token Txns" on Etherscan

Tags: etherscan

I am looking at this particular wallet address (0x2138a12520c9b45bb4b2c742923b514d5f662fec) and it shows that there are only 2 regular "Transactions" but 13,263 "Erc20 Token Txns" - why is there this discrepancy? I was under the assumption "Erc20 Token Txns" were a subset of "Transactions".

https://etherscan.io/address/0x2138a12520c9b45bb4b2c742923b514d5f662fec

Answer (score 1):

The txs under the Transaction tab are ETH transaction (transfers or methods called), whereas those under the ERC20 tab are only related to tokens (tracked through Transfer events). If you call a method that transfers tokens out of the contract for example, you should see new entries in both lists. If some other contract sends ERC20 tokens to your address, you'll only see an entry in the tokens tab.

From the official [info page](https://info.etherscan.com/explore-contract-address/) from Etherscan:

> Transactions: This tab shows all the ingoing and outgoing transactions involving the address sorted in a chronological order.

> Erc20 Token Txns: ERC-20 token transfers' history are located under
> this tab and are separated from the ETH transactions under the
> Transactions tab.